# Scroll a hidden view/layout from bottom

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

This is what I want to achieve :
[image]

I wanted to use AbsoluteLayout but it is deprecated. 
So I made a RelativeLayout beneath the blue view in the image above, and then put everything inside a ScrollView, but the hidden view is still 'on' the blue view, and not below it. Also, the screen scrolls, but the hidden part is just cut , and instead I see the my app's default background..

Any ideas?

EDIT : 
my current try :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/imageView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/centerHolder"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

       .....
       .....
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1000dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_holder"
        android:background="@color/black_color">

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: please add code for your layout

Comment: do you have used CoordinatorLayout ? CollapsingToolbarLayout ? NestedScrollView ?

Comment: No.. do I have to? I was hoping to implement it with just ScrollView

Comment: `CoordinatorLayout` will handle that nicely for you.

Comment: @Amy I wanted to use bottom sheet, but as far as I understand I have to put all the layout inside CoordinatorLayout(instead of the scrollview) , but when I tried it, it crashed ..

Comment: What exactly crashed? Maybe you called `findViewById` for your (then replaced) `ScrollView`? :)

Comment: @Amy How should I place the child views in the CoordinatorLayout? If I was using Relative or Linear layout, how do I correctly place everything into Coordinator now?
Do I even have to use CorrdinatorLayout in order to add a bottom sheet?
Thank you!

Comment: I posted an answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am taking this from a project of mine which displays a `RecyclerView` where you can add data if you click on a row - because the click "opens" the bottom sheet.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".view.fragment.BlockFragment">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/ll_header"
            layout="@layout/layout_header_names" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/divider_header"
            layout="@layout/layout_divider_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll_header" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_block"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/divider_footer"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider_header" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/divider_footer"
            layout="@layout/layout_divider_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#767676"
            android:layout_above="@+id/ll_footer" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/ll_footer"
            layout="@layout/layout_footer_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Here comes my bottom sheet.
         It is wrapped inside a FrameLayout, because an include cannot 
         have a behaviour. The included layout is every layout you 
         can imagine - mine is a RelativeLayout with two EditTexts 
         for example. The layout_behaviour is the second important line.  -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#e3e3e3"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_sheet"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

For the behaviour itself, you'll need to get the `FrameLayout` (the `View` with the `app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"`).

```
private BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;

bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.container_bottom_sheet);

//for the sheet to "peek":
bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(200);


//now you can set the states:
bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
```

It is also possible to set a `BottomSheetCallback()` in which you can get all the state changes and also the slideOffset!

```
    bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            switch (newState) {
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING:
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:
                    break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED:
                default:

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I'll update on the progress later on today, but it seems exactly what I need. Thanks

Comment: No problem! Feel free to ask me any question :)

Comment: I added the line to set a "peek" Behaviour, because I forgot.. ^^

Comment: weird.. it keeps crashing when trying to inflate the layout

Comment: `Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: This is indeed a weird error. Have you added the corresponding dependency? (`compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'` Minimum version should be the `22.2.0`) Other possible error types might be an incompatible `Theme` or `Style`,or maybe the use of `Activity` instead `AppCompatActivity`..?

Comment: I'm using `compile 'com.android.support:design:+'`.. 
and my activity extends Activity , not AppCompatActivity.

Comment: You'll need to change that, unfortunately

Comment: ugh.. :/ 
if I change to AppCompatActivity I'm getting a different crash :
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
`

Comment: Then use an `AppCompat` theme... :/ In your `styles.xml` change the `AppTheme`s parent to something like this `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` (if you use your own toolbar)

Comment: So I managed to figure out a workaround for that issue..
Now for some reason the recyclerview is not showing in my bottomsheet..
it shows some textviews and imageviews I have in the bottomsheet layout but not the recyclerview

Comment: This may be content for another question, since I and others cannot tell how you app looks like now.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should just use `LinearLayout` to wrap the `ImageView` and other layouts.

Edited the answer based on comments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/centerHolder"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

               .....
               .....
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1000dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/centerHolder"
            android:background="@color/black_color">

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: but then the centerHolder layout is not in the center of screen. Technically it is in the center of the parent, but it considers the parent as the the whole layout including the height of the hidden part of the bottom view - and so it always appears at the bottom of the screen then I open the fragment. (the scrolling seems to work though)

Comment: would I be able to place horizontal RecyclerViews inside? (part of the RecyclerView hidden at the bottom and you can scroll up to see fully see them)

Comment: You can try, I believe it should work. Otherwise you need to disable the horizontal scroll on the ScrollView and have it on the RecyclerView.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace your `ScrollView` with `NestedScrollView`

Example:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

Answer (score 2):

I realized you need something like this, just tested it out ,  just copy two files and see how it works.

```
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LinearLayout movableLL;
    boolean mDragLockGained;
    float initialTouchPoint;
//    int cutoffElevation;
    boolean inAnimation;
    ScrollView scrollView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

    movableLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mobileLL);
    movableLL.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (inAnimation) return true;
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mDragLockGained = true;
                    initialTouchPoint = event.getRawY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    performTranslation(event);
                    initialTouchPoint = event.getRawY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mDragLockGained = false;
                    performSettlingAnimation();
                    break;

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}


private void performTranslation(MotionEvent event) {
    float newDelta = event.getRawY() - initialTouchPoint;
    float currentY = movableLL.getTranslationY();
    if (currentY + newDelta > 0) {
        movableLL.setTranslationY(currentY + newDelta);
        if (scrollView.getTranslationY() + newDelta < 0){

        }
            scrollView.setTranslationY(scrollView.getTranslationY() + newDelta);
    } else {
        movableLL.setTranslationY(currentY);
        scrollView.setTranslationY(scrollView.getTranslationY());
    }
}

final int SETTLE_ANIMATION_DURATION = 300;

private void performSettlingAnimation() {
    ObjectAnimator animLl = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(movableLL, "translationY",
            movableLL.getTranslationY(), convertDpToPixels(this, 150));
    inAnimation = true;
    animLl.setDuration(SETTLE_ANIMATION_DURATION);
    animLl.start();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            inAnimation = false;
        }
    }, SETTLE_ANIMATION_DURATION);//use animationListener here as a best practice and toggle values in
    //on animation start and cancel/finish
    ObjectAnimator animSv = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(scrollView, "translationY", scrollView.getTranslationY()
            , 0);
    animSv.setDuration(SETTLE_ANIMATION_DURATION);
    animSv.start();
}


public static int convertDpToPixels(Context context, int dp) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
    );
}
}
```

and the xml......

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello There" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello Again" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="WhatsUp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="See ya" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mobileLL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:translationY="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#99ff0000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#990000ff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Please let me know if I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

For this purposes the best way is to use BottomSheet from Design Support Library from my point of view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1000dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white">

                <!-- other layout -->

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="120dp"
 app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It also possible to combine it with your own a CoordinatorLayout Behavior to change scroll position for your scroll view, if needed.

Comment: Can I just add the element as you wrote here (meaning, a FrameLayout with BottomSheet Behavior) without placing it all into a CroodinatorLayout ?

Comment: BottomSheetBehavior should be a child view of a CoordinatorLayout. There is some issue with that?

Comment: yes, when I place all my layout into a CoordinatorLayout , it doesn't work.. it doesn't even generate the visual layout in the design layout i Android Studio. And obviously crashes too

Comment: I was able to do it with layout that you provided above. I updated the answer :) I hope it helps!

Comment: well the ScrollView can be removed , because I'm now trying to use BottomSheet on the original layout.. I'll check that, hope it works now, I'll update you.

Comment: I'm getting `Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag FrameLayout` on the line : `app:behavior_peekHeight`

Comment: Did you add compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0' to your build.gradle file?

Comment: yep.. I compile `compile 'com.android.support:design:+'`

Comment: Your version should be at least 23.2.0 to able to use this feature. http://android-developers.blogspot.com.by/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html So I recommend to set version explicitly, because it should work ;)

Comment: `+` picks the highest version as far as I know. I tried with 23.3.0 however, and the issue remains.

Comment: Hmm, try to clean the project and sync gradle again

Comment: I experimented a little bit, I get the same error only if i remove design support library. "targetSdkVersion" and "compileSdkVersion" are 23?